# Need help getting Scope Values for X,Y Coordinates from an AngularJS Directive for GAE Image Crop Tool

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, angularjs, crop, angularjs-scope

Trying to build a photo cropping interface tool for GAE with AngularJS.

GAE accepts data in this form,
crop(left_x, top_y, right_x, bottom_y)
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/imageclass#Image_crop

I've gotten pretty far but I need some help with getting the values for X,Y coordinates out of what i think might be jQlite from inside a Directive and into a Scope that can be sent to the server.

Here is the full code in its current state - http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle2501/jnb88/1/

Bellow is the code for the Crop Area Directive -

```
crop.directive('croparea', function($document) {
return {
    scope: {
        size: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        var startX = 25, startY = 25, x = 25, y = 25;

        element.css({
            position: 'relative',
            outline: '1px solid lightgrey',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(20, 20, 30, .1)',
            cursor: 'move',
            top: startY + 'px',
            left: startX + 'px',
            margin: '25px',
        }); /// - element.css

        scope.update_size = function() {
            var width = scope.size, height = scope.size;
            element.css({
                width: width + 'px',
                height: height + 'px',
            }); /// - element.css
        }; /// - scope.update_size

        element.bind('mousedown', function(event) {
            startX = event.screenX - x;
            startY = event.screenY - y;
            $document.bind('mousemove', mousemove);
            $document.bind('mouseup', mouseup);
        });

        function mousemove(event) {
            y = event.screenY - startY;
            x = event.screenX - startX;
            element.css({
                top: y + 'px',
                left: x + 'px',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(20, 20, 30, .3)',
            });
        }

        function mouseup(scope) {
            $document.unbind('mousemove', mousemove);
            $document.unbind('mouseup', mouseup);
            element.css({
                top: y + 'px',
                left: x + 'px',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(20, 20, 30, .1)',
            });
        }

        scope.$watch( 'size', function() {
            scope.update_size();
        } );

    } /// - link
} /// - return
```

}) /// - directive

Thank you for help, suggestions, and advice! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If remove margin from cropper, values are easy to get:

```
{
      left_x: x,
      top_y:y,
      right_x: x +1*scope.size, /* size is string on change*/
      bottom_y: y+1*scope.size
}
```

I added a way to visualize changes by adding a scope.coorde to controller and passing that into directive so can print while playing. You will see 2 ways to update the coordinates. One is within `.$watch('size')`. Since the scope update within a `$watch` is moitored by angular this version simply changes the coordinates.

WHen you update scope from within an external event however , have to use `$.apply` so angular is aware of changes and will do a digest to update DOM. Used `mouseup` to make other update of coordinates.

Come to think of it...can probably use `ng-` events instead of using `element.bind` which would automatically update DOM without `$apply`

`ng-change` for range input would remove the watch for size.

`ng-mouseup` would remove need for `$.apply` I used

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jnb88/4/)**</kbd>